# Sending char * to string c#

Tags: c#, c

i have a function with 2 parameters in `c`. both of them are `char *`.
one of them is input and another one is output and i don' know what should I fill the second one (output) please help me

```
 // C
 void func1(char * i_szInput , char * o_szOutput)
 {
    printf("%s\n" ,  i_szInput );
    strcpy(o_szOutput , "Hello");
 }

 // C#
 [DllImport("Test.dll")]
 public static void func1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str1, 
                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str2);


// .......

 string str = null;
 func1("mytest" , str);
```

Comment: You should use `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder`. From MSDN [Marshaling Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8w969hb)

> String by reference: Passes strings as In/Out parameters using StringBuilder.

```
 [DllImport("Test.dll")]
 public static void func1([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str1,
                          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder str2);

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
func1("mytest", str);
```

See *[Default Marshaling for Strings: Fixed-Length String Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor3) (MSDN)*.

Comment: @Ria `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr), Out()] StringBuilder str2` or `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out StringBuilder str2`? And shouldn't you define a size for the `StringBuilder`?

Comment: [Buffers Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3txb6xc.aspx) MSDN for marshalling unmanaged `LPSTR` type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str = String.Empty;
func1("mytest", out str);
```